# WHERE attribute having two relation lines in the same SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, join

I have a database designed with tree tables:

```
checklist (id, name)
tag (id, name)
checklist_tag (checklist_id - FK, tag_id - FK)
```

Running this SQL:

```
SELECT cc.id as checklist_id, cc.name as checklist_name, ct.name as tag_name 
FROM checklist cc INNER JOIN checklist_tag cct ON cc.id = cct.checklistId 
INNER JOIN tag ct ON cct.tagId = ct.id 
WHERE ct.name IN ('tag 1', 'tag 2')
```

I get this result:

```
checklist_id    checklist_name  tag_name
1               checklist 1     tag 1
1               checklist 1     tag 2
3               checklist 3     tag 2
4               checklist 4     tag 2
```

But I need to select the checklists having the tags 1 and 2. Something like this:

```
checklist_id    checklist_name  tag_name
1               checklist 1     tag 1
1               checklist 1     tag 2
```

Is there anyway to do that with a single select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery that has the checklist id that has both tags

```
SELECT
    B.id checklist_id,
    B.name checklist_name,
    D.name tag_name
FROM
(
    SELECT AA.checklistId,COUNT(1) tagcount
    FROM checklist_tag AA
    INNER JOIN tag BB ON AA.tagId = BB.id
    WHERE BB.name IN ('tag 1', 'tag 2')
    GROUP BY AA.checklistId HAVING COUNT(1)=2
) A
INNER JOIN checklist B     ON A.checklistId = B.id
INNER JOIN checklist_tag C ON A.checklistId = C.checklist_id
INNER JOIN tag D           ON C.tag_id = D.id;
```

Comment: It worked perfectly!